# jquery $.post not working in Firefox

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, firefox

I am begging to use jquery.  I have the following call that works in IE7 but not FF 3.0.4.  But if I change the `null` to `{}` it works fine.  Is null not valid for this case and I just got lucky that it worked in IE or is this an error with jquery.

```
$.post("complexitybar.ashx?a=init&vc=" + validationCode, null, loadInitialValues, "json");
```

Comment: Could you perhaps explain why you want to use null?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try [`$.get()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.get) for query-string requests:

```
$.get('complexitybar.ashx?a=init&vc=...')
```

POST requests expect the URL and key-value pairs to be seperate:

```
$.post('complexitybar.ashx', 'a=init&vc=...')
```

With POST requests, the key-value pairs are sent as content data rather than as part of a URI.

Answer (score 1):

Since the parameter you are attempting to pass `null` to [is supposed to](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.post) represent a key-value pair of data you want to pass to the url you are posting to, it probably makes alot more sense to use an empty object (`{}`) that `null`.

`null` isn't treated the same way as you might expect it would be if you are thinking of a language such as Java.

Answer (score 0):

try   $.ajajx    with th e method "POST" , will be better